# ASP.NET/VB.NET error message saying " '#ButtonName#' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to it's protection level."

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, nullreferenceexception

I'm adding to an existing web app that has ASP.NET on the front end and VB.NET on the back end. I'm getting this error when I try to compile the code:

> '#ButtonName#' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to it's
>   protection level.

Here is my ASP.NET code:

```
<ajaxToolKit:TabPanel ID="MedicaidDataSubTabReadyToBill" runat="server" HeaderText="Ready To Bill">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="MedicaidDataReadyToBillPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="formRow" style="border:1px">
                   <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" Text="Save" width="70px" Visible ='false'/>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</ajaxToolKit:TabPanel>
```

And here is the code behind that is referencing the button "btnSave":

```
Protected Sub MedicaidDataReadyToBill_Search_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MedicaidDataReadyToBill_Search.Click
    If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(uxMedicaidDataReadyToBill_SchoolYear.Text) Or _
        (Me.uxMedicaidDataReadyToBill_ddCategory.SelectedIndex = 0)) Then
        lblPageError.Text = "*All fields are required."
    Else
        btnSave.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried to initialize the btnSave at the start of the code behind sub but that didn't work. Please someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Here is requested code:

```
Partial Class MedicaidBillingAdmin_medicaidbillingadmin
    Inherits BasePage


    Dim ChildGridUniqueID As String = String.Empty
    Dim ChildGridEditIndex As Integer = -1

    Dim NursingChildGridUniqueID As String = String.Empty
    Dim NursingChildGridEditIndex As Integer = -1

    Dim MedicaidDataGridUniqueID As String = String.Empty
    Dim MedicaidDataGridEditIndex As Integer = -1

    Dim MedicaidDataReadyToBillGridUniqueID As String = String.Empty
    Dim MedicaidDataReadyToBillGridEditIndex As String = -1


    Dim remoteDirectory As String = "//FromUHIN//"
    Dim localDirectory As String = "C:\test\"
    Dim port As Int32 = 22

    Public ExpandLink As StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder("")
    Public ExpandLink_Nursing As StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder("")
    Public Class Medicaid_Students
        Public Property strSchool_ID As String
        Public Property strCat As String
        Public Property strStudentID As String
        Public Property strStudentDistID As String
        Public Property strLastName As String
        Public Property strFirstName As String
        Public Property strDOB As String
        Public Property strMedicaidID As String
        Public Property strBillingCode As String
        Public Property strIEPDueDate As String
        Public Property intGrade As Int16
    End Class
```

Comment: Does btnSave exist in the .designer.vb file?

Comment: Can you please share the @Page directive located at the top of your aspx page? Also, share the class declaration code (including inherits) from aspx.vb file

Comment: `<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Mercury.Master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="MedicaidBillingAdmin.aspx.vb" Inherits="MedicaidBillingAdmin_medicaidbillingadmin" title="Medicaid Billing" %>`

Comment: `Partial Class MedicaidBillingAdmin_medicaidbillingadmin
    Inherits BasePage


    Dim ChildGridUniqueID As String = String.Empty
    Dim ChildGridEditIndex As Integer = -1

    Dim NursingChildGridUniqueID As String = String.Empty
    Dim NursingChildGridEditIndex As Integer = -1

    Dim MedicaidDataGridUniqueID As String = String.Empty
    Dim MedicaidDataGridEditIndex As Integer = -1

    Dim MedicaidDataReadyToBillGridUniqueID As String = String.Empty
    Dim MedicaidDataReadyToBillGridEditIndex As String = -1`

Comment: @Gharbad_The_Weak do not write code in comments! It is unreadable. Just [edit] your question adding the code requested

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The original post has been updated.

Comment: How about naming the button `ID="MedicaidDataReadyToBill_Search"` or `Handles btnSave.Click` either way these should match

Answer (score 0):

If the control "btnSave" is not recognized in the code behind, double check the designer file MedicaidBillingAdmin.aspx.designer.vb to make sure it's there. You might have to delete the designer file and create it again for the control to be accessible.